# How can convert a 2D CNN model to 3D CNN in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, 3d, conv-neural-network, 2d

I want use EfficientNet v2  for my work. there is some implementation for 2D Conv in GitHub like:

https://github.com/GdoongMathew/EfficientNetV2

I want convert this to 3D conv. Is it done with only converting evray thing that is 2D in code in 3D or need other config?

Comment: One possibility is to add some preprocessing layers to convert your input to the size fitting your 2D model then add your 2D model. Or the better way is to use the 3D implementations of such as what [ZFTurbo](https://github.com/ZFTurbo/efficientnet_3D) did.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the zfturbo implementation of efficientnet have problem with allocation of memory.